# Roots of Unity of a specific argument

Tags: complex-analysis, roots-of-unity

I am asked to find an unstable period 5 point for $f(z)=z^2$ with an argument which lies between -0.74 and -0.44.

I can solve to get all the roots of unity, but how can I narrow it down the the one that will have an argument between -0.74 and -0.44?

Comment: Whats an "unstable period 5 point of $\;z^2\;$ " ??

Comment: An unstable fixed point of $f^5$ (where the exponent means iteration, not multiplication) that is not a fixed point of $f$, @DonAntonio.

Comment: thanks @DanielFischer . Where does this terminology belong to?

Comment: Dynamical systems, I'd say, @DonAntonio.

Comment: @user, by "solve to get all the roots of unity", which ones do you refer to?

Comment: De nada, @Don, is a mekhaye.

Comment: Hmmm..."mekhaye"? It seems to be "a pleasure", from "Mekhaye nefashot", in hebrew. This english-writing of yiddisch kills me sometimes..Dank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation to solve is thus $f^5(z)-z=z^{32}-z=0$. Which gives $z=0$ and the unit roots of degree $31$. So you have to find all $k$ such that $$\frac{2\pi}{31}k\in[-0.74 , -0.44].$$

This can be transformed into an interval for $k$.

---

For this point to be unstable you need $1<|f'(z)|=32\cdot |z^{31}|$, which obviously is satisfied for all unit roots.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I need to multiply -0.74 and -0.44 by 31, then divide by 2pi, and use the numbers in this interval as a value for k to find my root?

Comment: Yes, that would seem the answer. And $z=0$ is the only stable fixed point.

Comment: Hi, this method works fine for me on most questions, so thank you for that, there are some cases where I am unable to get a correct answer. For period 7 of z^2 with an argument between 0.09 and 0.16, I get an interval of 1.819 and 3.234 and neither k=2 or 3 will give me a correct answer. The same situation also arises when I am dealing with negative arguments, e.g. period 7 of z^2, between -0.25 and -0.18 which gives me and interval of -5.053 and -3.638 and neither -4 nor -5 will give me a correct answer
What should my approach be in this situation? Thanks again

Comment: For $k=2$ I get $z\approx 0.995108659+i\cdot 0.0987864183$ with an angle of $0.098947800$. What precisely tells you that it is not in the correct answer?

Comment: I'm using maple TA which generates questions and then provides instant feedback as to whether the answer is correct or not. Using Derive for k=2, e^(i2pi(2)/127)=0.9951086591 + 0.09878641830*i, the same as yourself, and for k=3 I get 0.9890057044 + 0.1478773697*i, both of which are shown by Maple TA as incorrect. The same applies for any questions where I get an interval such as this one. Works fine for anything else for example an interval of 1.03... and 2.17..., where I would use k=2

Comment: Then you should probably contact the makers of maple TA. Either there is an error in the software or in the problem description, such things happen. Is the task description published somewhere online?

Comment: It's a set of 10 questions, all in the following form:
Find an unstable point of period 7 for the function f(z) = z^2, with argument between 0.09 and 0.16 radians.
I'll send an email tonight and see what they say about these particular questions.